# Wigner's formula for the kinetic energy density in QM

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, hamiltonian, boundary-conditions

In the Schroedinger equation the kinetic energy is represented by the operator $T = -\frac {\hbar^2} {2m} \Delta$ which acts on a wavefunction $\Psi$. If we multiply this by the complex conjugate of the wavefunction we get the following density in position space:

$$Schroedinger: K = -\frac {\hbar^2} {2m} \Psi^{*} \Delta \Psi$$

Now this is not the only density used in QM for the kinetic energy. Eugene Wigner developed his own version of quantum mechanics, based on the concept of a phase space representation, in which position and momentum are treated on equal footing in a single function. Wigner designed his phase space function in a such way, that when the function is multiplied by $k^2$ and integrated over momentum space, the following expression for the kinetic energy density results:

$$Wigner : K = \frac {\hbar^2} {2m} [(\nabla \Psi^{*}).(\nabla \Psi) \space-\space \Psi^{*} \Delta \Psi]/2$$

Was this choice necessary? No, not at all. In fact Wigner could have chosen a phase space representation which, after multiplication with $k^2$ and integration over momentum, leads to the Schroedinger density. In fact this alternative phase space function is much simpler, almost trivial, and is nowadays known as the Kirkwood-Rihaczek phase space representation. It seems logical that Wigner knew this, and preferred his own phase space function, because its properties are superior to that of Kirkwood-Rihaczek. And one of these superior properties is the kinetic energy density. Indeed, the Wigner phase space function is nowadays recognized as the "best" of its kind. Whereas Kirkwood-Rihaczek is sometimes considered a useful alternative, because it is fairly simple.

If the Wigner density for the kinetic energy is indeed superior to the Schroedinger choice, in the sense that it describes the physics of a quantum system better, a lot of questions arise. Can we use the Wigner expression in a Hamiltonian, and then use it to determine the evolution (time dependence) of our quantum system? Apparently not. What might be the reason? And if both densities are meaningful, what is the physics behing the difference between the two expressions?

Comment: Which references? Which pages?

Comment: K densities are basically defined up to a universally ignorable surface term, in the case of your Wigner (wrong) formula: $(ℏ^2/2m)(∇⋅(Ψ^* ∇Ψ)/2−Ψ^*ΔΨ)$.  If you follow the rules of Wigner's prescription, you actually find somewhat different surface terms, which, again, don't matter. The anti-standard ordering Kirkwood-Rihaczek prescription probably yields different surface terms--I have not checked your claim they are zero; but, again, why do you care? It is understood that all orderings yield the same effective K. Please clarify.

Comment: You might not be aware that your expressions for both the Wigner and K-R prescriptions were actually derived by *assuming* wholesale discarding of surface terms in the first place, exploiting the reality of K ! You'd find different total divergence terms using any of the alternate equivalent expressions for them! You might wish to review the [modern theory](https://www.hep.anl.gov/czachos/aaa.pdf).

Comment: @Cosmas Zachos. Thank you. There is nothing wrong with my formulas. It is clear that Wigner's expression has the same expectation value as Schroedinger's. The point is that they have a different dependence on $r$, and hence different physical properties. I would like to know whether this difference is acknowledged and discussed in the physics literature. The article you linked does not say anything about this matter.

Comment: The booklet I linked contrasts different prescriptions without diffidence towards integration by parts. Alternate calculations in it yield similar but also different expressions to yours. Dismissing total divergences is long understood to not affect the physis, expectation values, and should be asked about in plain QM. Phase space quantization is a red herring here. Would you like a demonstration with a Wigner function missing the final surface term?

Comment: There are three questions/misunderstandings colliding here: 1) Ignorability of total divergence terms in QM densities in standard QM, apart from deformation quantization. 2) Regarding Wigner-Weyl type  phase-space maps as  recipes for a "correct" quantization, a huge conceptual error. 3) Misappreciating the laebility/arbitrariness of the surface terms in different ordering prescriptions of deformation quantization which are routinely discarded as they depend on the formal pathways in evaluating such maps. Focussing on one of the three would make meaningful answers possible.